# Insert UTC/GMT date in Oracle database with Java and Spring

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timezone, spring-jdbc

When I insert `new Date()` object using `jdbcTemplate` to Oracle database, I can see that jdbc driver or Spring jdbcTemplate insert `Date` using local JVM offset.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date timeZoneDate = sdf.parse("09-SEP-1987");
```

For example when I insert Date object created in GMT this result to inserting 08-SEP-1987 in Oracle database if JVM timezone is USA.

Comment: How is the related column in your database declared?

Comment: In database I've got DATE type

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Neither `java.util.Date` nor Oracle `Date` stores timezone information. In your case Jdbc driver converts your date using the JVM timezone. You can use one of the following options:

- If you are using PreparedStatement, you can use `setDate(int
  parameterIndex, Date x, Calendar cal)` method to specify `Calendar`
  in UTC timezone.
- For Spring `jdbcTemplate` instead of inserting `Date` object, insert `Calendar` with `UTC` timezone
- `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))` could be set on JVM lvl
- Use `-Duser.timezone=GMT` on JVM startup

Comment: Didn't know about inserting a Calendar object. Nice!

Comment: +1, springjdbc template with calendar object works nicely for me

Answer (score 4):

The Oracle [`DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref151) datatype doesn't have a timezone field. It stores only the date and time components. Therefore when `jdbc` inserts a date with a timezone into a `DATE` database field, it has to decide what to do with the timezone information that will disappear.

In your case, it seems that `jdbc` converts the java `Date` to the locale time zone before inserting. The date `09-SEP-1987 00:00:00 UTC` is converted to `08-SEP-1987 20:00:00 EST` and the timezone information is dropped on insert.

Knowing that, you can either not specify a timezone when inserting into a `DATE` field so that the default locale time zone will be used or modify both the default time zone and the java `Date` timezone.

Comment: Conversion to local timezone is a requirement from the JDBC API doc: _"Sets the designated parameter to the given java.sql.Date value using the default time zone of the virtual machine that is running the application."_ [PreparedStatement.setDate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date,%20java.util.Calendar))

Comment: Does this conversion happen too when your Oracle column data type is a timestamp?

Comment: @supertonsky The Oracle [`TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-E2DB6A6E-FBCA-49B1-B8F0-D13A5B8BCB14.htm) datatype doesn't have a timezone component, so the behaviour should be the same. You can use the [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-DBCD234A-8355-4130-A5B3-B8231F0088AF.htm#SUTIL1171) datatype if you want to store time zone data.