# Java date long value changed after insert, select query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timezone

AFAIK, java Date type is independent from Timezone which means that it represents specific moment of time as long typed value. I found really weird thing here.

This is the original value i tried to insert.

**(http-0.0.0.0-9080-4) 1352955600000  <-- long integer.**

**(http-0.0.0.0-9080-4) Thu Nov 15 00:00:00 EST 2012  <-- User Friendly Format.**

After i finished inserting into Oracle 11g database, the value has changed!

**(http-0.0.0.0-9080-4) 1352952000000**

**(http-0.0.0.0-9080-4) Wed Nov 14 23:00:00 EST 2012**

How could this happen?? The more weird thing is it only happens specific environments such as Jboss.
I'm currently using below environments.

- java 1.6
- ibatis 2.34
- jboss-5.1 (server)
- tomcat 6.0 (local)
- oracle 11g

Is there anybody who can give me a clue or link to be helpful?
it really bugging me!!

---

I adds more information here.
I uses Date type in java, and TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE in oracle.

I stored value ("11/15/2012", MM/dd/yyyy, US/Eastern) in Date.

And Sent this value to Oracle using iBatis.And it shows like

**12/11/15 00:00:00.000000000 -04:00**

which is incorrect. It's time zone should be -05:00 because DST will has ended in November.

And more, when i get this value from my java code,

it returns  **Wed Nov 14 23:00:00 EST 2012** , which i expected as **Thu Nov 15 00:00:00 EST 2012**.

**Problem Solved.**

Thanks Folks. I found the reason. It's known bug of ojdbc driver.
Please refer this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=354702).

Comment: Probably a timezone mismatch between your db and the application (java), see [Insert UTC date in Oracle database with Java and Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563553/insert-utc-date-in-oracle-database-with-java-and-spring)

Comment: What is your database Timezone?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Thanks! But timezone only matters with "presentation" right? How timezone modify the absolute value over DB?..

Comment: Your client session has a default time zone (determined from Locale), when you insert a Date it is converted to the database time zone.

Comment: In the DB is it a Date column or a long column (whatever the DB-Specific types are in oracle)?

Comment: @Annjawn I'm using DB with US/Eastern. But It works well in local environments. This only happen Developer's server which uses same DB!

Comment: @Fildor  The column's data type is TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE.

Comment: We probably also need to see how it's being used - the fact that it's being modified at all is a bit worrisome.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Thanks! Vincent! does client session mean connection  between Database and WAS data-source pool right? I'm still wondering that if date has converted according to database time zone, does it affects to its absolute value?

Comment: I don't know how someone hasn't asked yet, but are you using `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`? If you're using the util one, you might be interested to read [this question about the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2305973/1313143). This may well explain your strange observations.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Hi Mario. I'm surely using java.util.Date. Application Developer usually does not use java.sql.Date. cause it's only wrapping class of java.util.Date to identify millisecond value for JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug of ojdbc.
After upgrading library, problem never happened.

Refer this

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/356702